# Text Size change buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeFontSize(element,step)
        {
            step = parseInt(step,10);
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            var curFont = parseInt(el.style.fontSize,10);
            el.style.fontSize=(curFont+step) +'px';
        }
    </script>

<button type="button" a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changeFontSize('content','2');">
    </a>A+</button>
    <button type="button" a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changeFontSize('content','-2');">
    </a>A-</button>
```

The text size buttons do not work on my website, they appear but when clicked they do not change the text size. I do have a div id called content.

Comment: for a start, you have a sort of badly formatted link inside a button. Probably best to delete the `<a>` and `hrefs` and only use a `<button>`

Comment: [See This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wared/JWUt9/) in jsFiddle. It will be help you... !!!

Comment: Add style to content as `el.style.fontSize` is returning `""`. Try this to #content div `style="font-size:12px"`

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a non-jquery solution without setting an initial size, you can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) to calculate the current font size. This work in everything including IE9+.

Other changes:

1. Remove `a` and `href` bit, just use a button.
2. `step` can be passed as a number rather than a string (works either way, but passing a number makes more sense)

```js
function changeFontSize(element, step) {
    //step = parseInt(step, 10); // no need for this line if pass as a number
    var el = document.getElementById(element);
    var curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize, 10);
    el.style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Some text...</div>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', -2);">A-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this instead:

```
function changeFontSize(step) {
    var size = $('p').css('font-size');
    $('p').css('font-size', (step+size)+'px');
}
```

Then call this function on your button click passing in the value for step.

This solution uses jQuery but will work without an issue.

You also need to set your starting size in your css file

Answer (score 0):

just small change all your code is ok

i.e. first set font size to your div

```
<div id="content" style="font-size:20px;">Test text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with jquery

```
$("#largefont").click(function(){

     var size = parseInt($("p").css('font-size').replace('px',''),10);
    //alert(size);
    if( size < 30){
    $("p").css('font-size', size+1);}
    else
    { alert("Max Font Size reached.")}

    });
   $("#smallfont").click(function(){

     var size = parseInt($("p").css('font-size').replace('px',''),10);
    //alert(size);
    if( size > 12){
    $("p").css('font-size', size-1);}
    else
    { alert("Min Font Size reached.")}

    });
```

checkout on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/go2whqja/